# swift3: How to Present xib to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3, presentviewcontroller

I have added xib on another xib class as subview and unable to present from xib to view controller (Story Board controller).
I tried following

1.

```
let screen:Screen32ViewController = Screen32ViewController()
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(screen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
```

2.

```
let screen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen32ViewController") as? Screen32ViewController
self.present(screen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
```

3.

```
let screen:Screen32ViewController = Screen32ViewController()
self.present(screen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
```

Non of this worked for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have navigation controller embedded into your Root view controller?

Comment: Yes i have root view controller (navigation controller).

Comment: The problem was solved by let screen = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen32ViewController") as?   Screen32ViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.present(screen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
let screen = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen32ViewController") as?   Screen32ViewController
self.present(screen!, animated: true,  completion: nil)
```

Comment: Its worked fine but i'm getting error in log "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"

Comment: present on self.navigationcontroller

Comment: i did it by self.window.rootviewcontroller.present and its worked fine without warning.
But unable to push using same code

Comment: let screen = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen32ViewController") as?   Screen32ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(screen!, animated: true)

Comment: by using navigation controller u can push that controller

Comment: I did like this but its not working self.navigationController?.pushViewController(screen!, animated: true)

Comment: i think navigation controller coming empty there , u can use window.rootviewcontrolller

Comment: But there is no method to perform push on  self.view.window?.rootViewController? we can only use push with navigation controller

Comment: (self.view.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(screen!, animated: true)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132456/discussion-between-mahesh-narla-and-andey-satyanarayana).